# What to do when too much shortening is added to flour?

Tags: flour, baking-powder, tortilla, shortening, flour-tortilla

I was trying to make some homemade flour tortillas, but I made a mistake and I added ~9oz of shortening to 4.5 cups of flour.

I'm unsure what to do with the flour mixture because I do not want just to throw it away.

I also added a tablespoon of salt and a tablespoon of baking powder and around of 1 1/2 cups of water.

Is the mixture still good for flour tortillas?

Comment: You might want to provide the actual recipe, and target ratio.

Comment: I just doubled the amount of shortening/lard to the mixture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet it to divide the dough into two batches, freezing half for later.

With the half you are working with, add 1/2 recipe worth of all the other ingredients again, except the lard.  This will bring you into balance.

The tortillas may be somewhat tougher than you would get if they were made to specification the first time, but that will avoid wasting your ingredients.

Still, given that the ingredients in a tortilla are generally inexpensive, you may decide it is not worth it, and simply discard the spoiled batch and start again.